# PHP Preg match for counting number of sentences in a paragraph

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I used a function to count number of sentences in a paragraph of string using preg_match but it does not seem to return the correct number of sentences.

This is the paragraph
I dreamt last night that I was hanging with Obama and he gave me his iPad password, which was "what if" i looked at him all confused and he just smiled. Last night I dreamed that I was bit by a pit bull/rattlesnake mix... What is wrong with me? Last night I dreamed that I was an HVAC specialist for an upscale office park in town... Lol. #whattheheck

This is the function i am using

```
function countSentences($str){
    return preg_match_all('/[^\s](\.|\!|\?)(?!\w)/',$str,$match);
}
```

For the above paragraph it returns 7 sentences instead of 6
Please advise what i can change

Thanks,
DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this piece of RegEx:

```
([^\.\!\?]+)
```

http://regexr.com?38f5v

Or this one (which will include the final characters too):

```
([^\.\!\?]+[\.\?\!]*)
```

http://regexr.com?38f6e